# Refresh a jframe from another class

Tags: java, swing, refresh, jframe, repaint

I want to refresh(repaint) a jframe if an event in other class occurred, I use some thing like code below but somethimes this code didn't work:

```
static Container container;
public FrameConstractor()
{
    ...
    container = getContentPane();
    ...
}

public static void refreshMethod()
{
    container.repaint();
}
```

and I call refresh method when my event occurred; but this code repaint the frame for me some times and some times didn't do any thing!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: `static Container..`  The keyword `static` cannot solve whatever this problem is.  Remove it.

Comment: `repaint()` may not be the solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem can be solved by changing refreshMethod to:

```
public static void refreshMethod()
{
    container.invalidate();
    container.validate();
}
```